# How to add a column to lists within a list without losing their names?

Tags: r, list, lapply

I did several attempts to add a specific column to data frames resp. lists within a list, but all `*apply()` attempts failed to preserve the names of the data frames.

For example for list `l`,

```
l <- list(alpha=data.frame(1:3), bravo=data.frame(4:6), charly=data.frame(7:9))

> l
$`alpha`
  X1.3
1    1
2    2
3    3

$bravo
  X4.6
1    4
2    5
3    6

$charly
  X7.9
1    7
2    8
3    9
```

I want the initial letters of the lists' names as a second `id` column. I tried these attempts who give me basically what I want:

```
lapply(seq_along(l), function(x) cbind(l[[x]], id=substr(names(l)[x], 1, 1)))
# or
lapply(seq_along(l), function(x) data.frame(l[[x]], id=substr(names(l)[x], 1, 1)))
# [[1]]
# X1.3 id
# 1    1  a
# 2    2  a
# 3    3  a
# 
# [[2]]
# X4.6 id
# 1    4  b
# 2    5  b
# 3    6  b
# 
# [[3]]
# X7.9 id
# 1    7  c
# 2    8  c
# 3    9  c
```

but the inner lists have lost their names. Option `USE.NAMES=TRUE` from `lapply()` documentation didn't work.

I also tried these two attempts, but they failed even worse.

```
lapply(seq_along(l), function(x) mapply(cbind, l[[x]], id=substr(names(l)[x], 1, 1), 
                                        SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
rapply(l, function(x) cbind(x, id=substr(names(l)[x], 1, 1)), how="list")
```

I know I could do this like so:

```
l1 <- lapply(seq_along(l), function(x) cbind(l[[x]], id=substr(names(l)[x], 1, 1)))
names(l1) <- names(l)
```

or do a `for` loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(l)) {
  l[[i]] <- data.frame(l[[i]], id=substr(names(l)[i], 1, 1))
}
```

but I'd like to know whether an `*apply()` solution could be improved to bring the expected output, which would be:

```
$`alpha`
  X1.3 id
1    1  a
2    2  a
3    3  a

$bravo
  X4.6 id
1    4  b
2    5  b
3    6  b

$charly
  X7.9 id
1    7  c
2    8  c
3    9  c
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `Map`

```
Map(`[<-`, l, "id", value = substr(names(l), 1, 1))
#$alpha
#  X1.3 id
#1    1  a
#2    2  a
#3    3  a

#$bravo
#  X4.6 id
#1    4  b
#2    5  b
#3    6  b

#$charly
#  X7.9 id
#1    7  c
#2    8  c
#3    9  c
```

The first argument is a function. `Map` then applies the function "to the first elements of each ... argument, the second elements, the third elements, and so on.", see `?mapply`.

Comment: This is indeed economical.

Answer (score 2):

`sapply` over the names with `simplify = FALSE`.

```
addId <- function(x) cbind(l[[x]], id = substring(x, 1, 1))
sapply(names(l), addId, simplify = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
$`alpha`
  X1.3 id
1    1  a
2    2  a
3    3  a

$bravo
  X4.6 id
1    4  b
2    5  b
3    6  b

$charly
  X7.9 id
1    7  c
2    8  c
3    9  c
```

Alternately:

```
replace(l, TRUE, lapply(names(l), addId))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind switching over to the `purrr::map` family from the `apply` family, `purrr::imap` takes 2 arguments: the item being mapped over, and the names of the item being mapped over. Then you can use your same `cbind` call, but you now have easy access to the names of the data frames.

```r
l <- list(alpha=data.frame(1:3), bravo=data.frame(4:6), charly=data.frame(7:9))

purrr::imap(l, function(df, name) cbind(df, id = substr(name, 1, 1)))
#> $alpha
#>   X1.3 id
#> 1    1  a
#> 2    2  a
#> 3    3  a
#> 
#> $bravo
#>   X4.6 id
#> 1    4  b
#> 2    5  b
#> 3    6  b
#> 
#> $charly
#>   X7.9 id
#> 1    7  c
#> 2    8  c
#> 3    9  c
```

Or if you want to go full `tidyverse`, you can add a column with `dplyr::mutate` inside your `imap`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

imap(l, function(df, name) df %>% mutate(id = str_sub(name, 1, 1)))
#> $alpha
#>   X1.3 id
#> 1    1  a
#> 2    2  a
#> 3    3  a
#> 
#> $bravo
#>   X4.6 id
#> 1    4  b
#> 2    5  b
#> 3    6  b
#> 
#> $charly
#>   X7.9 id
#> 1    7  c
#> 2    8  c
#> 3    9  c
```

As noted by @markus, you can also use the `~.` formula notation shorthand instead of spelling out your functions. In that case, `purrr::imap`'s two arguments become `.x` (the data frames) and `.y` (the names). This looks like:

```r
purrr::imap(l, ~cbind(.x, id = substr(.y, 1, 1)))
```

Comment: Yup. I generally like writing my functions out, at least at first, for clarity for myself and for SO readers. But thanks for reminding me

Comment: Sorry, the comment was not meant as know-it-all.

Comment: No problem, didn't take it as such! I don't often use the formula notation, so I forget that others really like it